# Creating a flag using CASE WHEN with multiple conditions in PROC SQL

Tags: case, proc-sql

I'm trying to create a flag indicating if a customer is a holistic customer based on different combinations of their subscription types.

```
ID  Subscriber_Type  
1   Online
1   Mail
1   Email
2   Online
2   Email
3   Email
3   Mail
```

If a customer's subscription is Online OR Email AND Mail, then the subscriber is holistic. So the final table would look like this:

```
ID  Subscriber_Type  Holistic
1   Online           Y
1   Mail             Y
1   Email            Y
2   Online           N
2   Email            N
3   Email            Y
3   Mail             Y
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is for sure a cleaner way to do this, but the following should give you the expected output.

```
data have;
infile datalines4 delimiter="|";
input id subscriber_type $;
datalines4;
1|Online
1|Mail
1|Email
2|Online
2|Email
3|Email
3|Mail
;;;;

proc transpose data=have out=stage1(drop=_name_);
by id;
var subscriber_type;
run;

data stage2(keep= id holistic);
set stage1;
cat = catx("|", of col:);
holistic = "N";
if (findw(cat, "Online") > 0 or findw(cat, "Email") > 0) 
     and findw(cat, "Mail") > 0 then holistic="Y";
run;

proc sql;
    create table want as
    select t1.id, subscriber_type, holistic
    from have t1 left join stage2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
quit;
```

Results:

```
 id subscriber_type holistic
 1     Email           Y
 1     Online          Y
 1     Mail            Y
 2     Email           N
 2     Online          N
 3     Mail            Y
 3     Email           Y
```